# "Make you some coffee" or "Make some coffee for you"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I was wondering which structure is the correct one:

> 1- Do you want me to **make you** some coffee? [Source](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/grammar/common-errors-with-verbs.htm) 
> 2- Do you want me to **make** some coffee **for you**?

I think the first one means: "Do you want that I turn you into coffee!" Therefore, the correct version would be #2 to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are idiomatic and natural.  They mean exactly the same.

Make you + adjective (make you happy) means cause you to be happy.

Make you + noun is technically ambiguous. Make you a table means fabricate a table for you. Make you a princess means turn you into a princess.  But there are few situations in which there is actual confusion.

Make you into + noun (make you into a princess) means turn you into a princess.

Comment: Thank you James. Just please let me know if there is any preference in everyday speech between these two structures or depending on any personal style they both can be used freely?

Comment: As James said, they are both entirely natural and acceptable.